What could be causing the farting noise in my 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan?
I have a 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan, approx. 155k miles. Drives well, no issues accelerating, turning, overheating. Has had regular oil changes and tire rotations. As far as I can tell, no transmission or engine issues though I'm always keeping my eye out.
For more than 5 years, there's been a persistent 'farting' noise that occasionally starts in the front passenger side of the car. Been to at least 3 mechanics about it, but no one can figure it out. However, I've noticed it correlates with the AC being on - and it happens almost everytime the car starts and the AC turns on immediately (bc it was on when I previously turned the car off). This isn't a hissing noise, but starts low pitched and the front passenger side and crescendos into a high pitched squeak somewhere in the rear of the car. This sound does not affect the car's performance, not even on hot days when the AC is running, but I choose to run the AC less as a result.
Could there be a hole in the AC refrigerant line, or something else of that nature? Regardless of the issue, what test(s) could I ask a mechanic to run on the AC system to either find the issue or rule this out?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
